# Using install.packages with custom temp dir

Tags: r, cran, devtools

I would like to install a package with a security profile that does not have access to `/tmp` , but has its own temporary directory, for example `/tmp/jeroen`. However even though I try to pass the `TMPDIR` environment variable, it still fails because it tries to use `/tmp`. Below a toy example using [RAppArmor](https://github.com/jeroenooms/RAppArmor) and [unixtools](https://github.com/s-u/unixtools) (see [here](http://pastebin.com/WTGtgZXA) for the test profile)

```
> library(RAppArmor)
> library(unixtools)

> dir.create("/tmp/jeroen")
> set.tempdir("/tmp/jeroen")
> setwd(tempdir());

> aa_change_profile("r-test")
Switching profiles...

> print(tempdir());
[1] "/tmp/jeroen"

> install.packages("plyr", lib="/tmp/jeroen", configure.vars="TMPDIR=/tmp/jeroen")
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/plyr_1.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 384462 bytes (375 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 375 Kb

Fatal error: cannot create 'R_TempDir'

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/jeroen/downloaded_packages’
```

When looking at the `kern.log` file (which logs security messages), it turns out that the problem is that `R CMD INSTALL` still tried to use `/tmp` which was denied:

```
Jul 24 19:41:34 Jeroen-Antec kernel: [16270.696805] type=1400 audit(1374687694.097:599):
apparmor="DENIED" operation="mkdir" parent=5798 profile="r-test" name="/tmp/RtmpcUOJuQ/"
pid=5802 comm="R" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Is there any way I can tell `R CMD INSTALL` to use `/tmp/jeroen` instead?

Comment: If you're going to set a TMPDIR environment variable, I believe you'd have to do it when starting R (or in a .Renviron file).  e.g. you'd need to start R like this `TMPDIR="/tmp/jeroen" R`

Comment: FWIW, `install.packages` makes 2 calls to `tempdir()`; it _might_ help to examine when it's called

Comment: @GSee I was hoping the `configure-vars` option would take care of that. The process does not have permission to edit .Renviron

Comment: While I don't know about this particular case, in the past I've had to go to great lengths to work around this (restarting R from within a script).  Here's a related [R-devel post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-February/063352.html)

Comment: have you tried the destdir argument ?

Comment: @Karl Downloading of the packages works fine, `destdir` will use `tempdir()` which has been taken care of. The problem appears later in the process when `install.packages` calls out to `R CMD INSTALL`.

Comment: @Jeroen set (then reset afterwards) in your script with `Sys.setenv()`. Environmental variables are inherited by child processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer was given by @hadley in the comments: in order to make sure `install.packages` uses the custom temporary directory, one needs to do

```
Sys.setenv(TMPDIR="/tmp/jeroen")
```

in addition to:

```
configure.vars="TMPDIR=/tmp/jeroen"
```

This way both the extraction and the installation of the package avoids the system or user default temporary directory.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation in `help(tempdir)` pretty clearly states that `TMP`, `TMPDIR`, ... are used:

> By default, ‘tmpdir’ will be the directory given by ‘tempdir()’.
>      This will be a subdirectory of the per-session temporary directory
>      found by the following rule when the R session is started.  The
>      environment variables ‘TMPDIR’, ‘TMP’ and ‘TEMP’ are checked in
>      turn and the first found which points to a writable directory is
>      used: if none succeeds ‘/tmp’ is used.

So if setting one alone does not help, maybe you want to set several, and make sure the permissions on your 'replacement directory' are permissive enough etc pp.

Comment: But where/how do I set these? The `configure-vars` doesn't help because it is only used when calling `./configure`. The problem appears earlier while extracting the `package.tar.gz`.

Comment: System-wide (`/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`) or application-wide (`$RHOME/etc/Renviron`), ditto for per-user.  Windoze has similar system-wide settings. You can also try `TEMPDIR=/foo TMP=/foo R CMD INSTALL ...` etc pp.  There is an entire manual devoted to this as you know.