# Can I specify where the sources downloaded to build R packages are going

Tags: r, build, installation

I know how to specify where packages I install via `install.packages` or `R CMD` are going.
When I install within `R` I always get the

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpxtIlp5/downloaded_packages’
```

Can I setup some environment or something so it always go where I want it to go ?

**EDIT**
Not sure if this is new but the good answer is to use `destdir`

```
install.packages(pkgs='versions', destdir='/tmp/sources', lib='/tmp/library', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841332/using-install-packages-with-custom-temp-dir) answer your question?

Comment: `tempdir()` did not know about this ! very good, I can get all sources from it. Like maybe in the `.Last()` function at close.

Answer (score 2):

I use the script `install.r` included as an example in the [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) package (which is also available as a binary for several Linux distrubtions including Debian and Ubuntu).  As a side-effect, it leaves packages in `/tmp/download_packages`:

```
edd@max:~$ install.r digest
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/digest_0.6.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 97985 bytes (95 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 95 KB

* installing *source* package ‘digest’ ...
** package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   [...]
gcc -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   [...]
[...]
gcc -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib [...]
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/digest/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (digest)

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/downloaded_packages’
edd@max:~$
```

As they are *not* delete (as done by the default R session) you could easily script it to copy them to some other directory.

Comment: I think `TMPDIR` (`?tempdir`) is a better way, though, as you suggested I will do the copy in `Last()`

Comment: It's all about scripting anyway. If you feel you need to control the download or source distination, split `install.packages()` into first downloading to wherever your heart desires and the installing from the (now-local) file. Rscript and/or r (from littler) make this trivial.

Comment: Doing this I think I'll loose the dependencies resolution (I think) best is to install,  then move the files.

Comment: Not sure if you can coax `install.packages()` into giving you the list of package fed to `download.packages()`.  My main point is that *you overcomplicate this* as I already pointed you to a solution satisfying your requirements: `install.r` into `/tmp/downloaded_packages` plus subsequent copy if desired.  And `install.r` **will** get all dependency-implied  packages for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dir` argument of `install`. Like so:

```
install.packages("yourPackage", dir="your/install/dir")
```

There is no global option in Rstudio for that argument. I poked around in the R directory, and couldn't find anything. As a global workaround:

```
installDir = "your/install/dir"
...
install.packages("yourPackage", dir=installDir)
```

Not ideal, but it will work.

Comment: I think you're answering the wrong/a dfferent question.