# Installation failed: Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION

Tags: r

I am trying to use this:

```
devtools::install_github("kbenoit/quanteda/quanteda.corpora")
```

But then I get this error:

```
Downloading GitHub repo kbenoit/quanteda@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/kbenoit/quanteda/zipball/master
Installation failed: Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: For packages from Github, you use the form `username/repo`. Going to github.com/kbenoit/quanteda rerouted me to a repo at `quanteda/quanteda`.  `quanteda/quanteda` is the location you use for installing. The installation instructions are on the repo's readme as well.

Comment: Thanks but  I have new error >>>    Installation failed: Can't find 'C:\Users\SBA\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAnuZQn\devtools17f826bf43af\quanteda-quanteda.corpora-91a3674'.

Answer (score 2):

The readme for this packages describes the correct syntax to install it [(see)](https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda.corpora#how-to-install):

```
devtools::install_github("quanteda/quanteda.corpora")
```

Comment: Thanks but there is this new error, could not figure it out. >>>  Installation failed: Can't find 'C:\Users\SBA\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAnuZQn\devtools17f826bf43af\quanteda-quanteda.corpora-91a3674'.

Comment: How odd. Have you checked if this folder exists? Have you restarted R? What are the other messages you get during installation?

Comment: I have restarted R, this is the error >>> Downloading GitHub repo quanteda/quanteda.corpora@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/quanteda/quanteda.corpora/zipball/master
Installation failed: Can't find 'C:\Users\SBA\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpC62Mx5\devtools15a01af22bc\quanteda-quanteda.corpora-91a3674'.

Comment: Have you tried installing a different package from github?For example `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`

Comment: devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2") Yes, this works.

Comment: It's not a problem of quanteda, I just checked. Did you look in the folder? Maybe it helps to delete `C:\Users\SBA\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpC62Mx5\devtools15a01af22bc\`

Comment: this part <C:\Users\SBA\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpC62Mx5\devtools15a01af22bc> comes from error. I am not writing this. It is the the thing what it gives to me actually. I have Iook in the folder, seems there is no problem..

Comment: I know but there seems to be some problem with this folder. Maybe it would help to use a different temporary directory https://stackoverflow.com/a/17881157/5028841

Comment: Okay, I ll go over it. I thank you for your time and helps. :)